# EF 6 Code First relationships using Fluent API. How to set relation between first and third tables or get grouped collection

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, relationship, ef-fluent-api

I have three related entities, here is a structure and relations declared using Fluent API

An event, participating many persons (actually a group of persons) so there is a possibility to collect them all by `GroupID`. So how to do this?

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string DocID { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> GroupPerson {get; set}
}
```

Person entity, here I have all information about person, such as name, surname, birthdate...

```
public class Person
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string PersonSurName { get; set; }
    public string PersonCode { get; set; } 
}
```

Group entity, here is an information about the group

```
public class Group
{
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Now I describe relations using Fluent API. Primary keys first of all:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasKey(e => e.EventID);  
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(e => e.PersonID);  
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(e => e.GroupID);
```

Here I will have person related to event

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(fk=> fk.PersonID);
```

Here I will have PersonGroup

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
               .HasKey(e => e.GroupID)
               .HasMany(e => e.EventGroup)
               .WithOptional()
               .HasForeignKey(f => f.GroupID);
```

And my question is how to set a relation to get that list of persons in group?
`PersonGroup` is an `Event` type and I need list of persons type: `Person => ICollection<Person> GroupPerson` in `Event` class.

Comment: you didn't use up your navigation property Event.GroupPerson. I'm not quite sure if that's intentional or not, it might lead to some ugly errors though. Regarding your question: you can add a navigation property, or better even two navigation property, unless Event is meant as a join table, which in turn would mean you'd have to do that over two joins. If it's not the case, you either add the navigation property(properties), add an FK to join in memory or use the .Join method.

Comment: I don't know how to describe navigation property Event.GroupPerson. Group.EventGroup returns me all related events, what I need to add person to that list

Comment: Actually I need Persons in events related by groupId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your relationships are like this:

- One event has (is related to) exactly one group (required)
- One group has (is related to) zero to many events
- One group has (is related to) zero to many people
- One person has (is related to) zero to many groups

That is, your relationship Events-Groups is one-to-many, and your relationship Groups-People is many-to-many (I'm assuming that the same person can be in more than one group). There is no direct relationship between Events and People, but a transitive relationship Event -> Group -> People.

Then it can be modelled like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string DocID { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get { return Group.People; } }
}

public class Person
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string PersonSurName { get; set; }
    public string PersonCode { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

With these DbSets in the `DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

And this EF configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasKey(e => e.EventID)
    .Ignore(e => e.People)
    .HasRequired(e => e.Group)
    .WithMany(g => g.Events);

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasKey(g => g.GroupID)
    .HasMany(g => g.People)
    .WithMany();

 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasKey(p => p.PersonID);
```

Note that there is an explicit `Ignore()` for `Event.People`. This is because the relationship between Event and Person is transitive, you don't need extra columns in your database for it. If you don't see why, try commenting out the `Ignore()` line and regenerating the migration, and see that an extra column for the Event ID is generated in the People table (this column doesn't make much sense).

As a consequence the `People` property in `Events` is not populated by EF, you have to do it yourself:

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get { return Group.People; } }
```

To add people to an Event you should use the Group navigation property, something like this:

```
public class Event
{
    ...

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        this.Group.People.Add(p);
    }
}
```

With this code the migration is generated like this, with four tables: `Events`, `Groups`, `People` and and extra table `PeopleGroups` for the many-to-many relationship between Person and Group.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Events",
            c => new
                {
                    EventID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DocID = c.String(),
                    GroupID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EventID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Groups", t => t.GroupID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.GroupID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Groups",
            c => new
                {
                    GroupID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    GroupName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.GroupID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    PersonName = c.String(),
                    PersonSurName = c.String(),
                    PersonCode = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.GroupPersons",
            c => new
                {
                    Group_GroupID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Person_PersonID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Group_GroupID, t.Person_PersonID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Groups", t => t.Group_GroupID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Person_PersonID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Group_GroupID)
            .Index(t => t.Person_PersonID);

    }
```

If you don't like the names of the columns in the relationship table `GroupPersons` you can add a `.Map()` configuration (but you don't really need to do this, as this table isn't directly used, there is no model entity for it, and it doesn't even have a `DbSet` property in the `DbContext`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have a problem here: modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasKey(g => g.GroupID)
    .HasMany(g => g.People)
    .WithMany();

Comment: {"ORA-00904: \"Extent2\".\"Group_KeyID\": invalid identifier"}

Comment: Do I need also put that public override void Up() in my code? As I understand, I need to create a reliation between Group and Person during Event

Comment: One more thing, I have everything in my project, only one I missing is values Group.Event.People. You know, I am trying to show list in a grid and I have a right count of records near, but not lucky to get person data, only events data and what the EF to do it for me...

Comment: I don't know why you get the "Invalid identifier error", try looking for something with name `KeyID` in your code. About the `Up()` method, it is automatically generated in every migration class, in addition to a `Down()` method, when running `Add-Migration` in Package Manager Console. You shouldn't have to write any code there. You don't define the relationships by writing the `Up`code, but by writing the `modelBuilder` configurations code. Check your existing migration classes to see the `Up` code there.

Comment: And about your third question: `Group.Events.People` is a strange way to access the list of `People`. Note that in this model for a given `Group` every single `Event` in `Group.Events` has the same list of `Person` instances. The right way to get the list of `People` would be `Event.Group.People`.